# JavaScript reflect property changes in all object references

Tags: javascript, reference

I need to loop through nested object classes and extract their properties in an object. But changing property values from inside the objects doesn't change values in the variable holding root object of these objects. When I check from inside the objects, new values are applied correctly.

However, if I add new properties instead of chaging existing properties, I can access the new ones.

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7rp1qxta/)

```
    var OO = function(o, parent){
        this.parent = parent || null;
        this.init(o);
        return this;
    };

    OO.prototype = {
        init: function(o){
            this.obj = typeof o === 'object' ? new OO(o.name, this) : o;
            this.type = typeof o === 'object' ? 'object' : 'string';

            if( typeof o === 'string' ){
                this.change();
                console.log(this.parent); // Here top-level oo object holds values called in change() function. I want the variable ( oo_var ) holding this top-level oo to have same property values too.
                this.add();
            }               
        },

        change: function(){
            this.parent.obj = 'Orange'; // Holds {} before changing
            this.parent.type = 'string'; // 'object' before changing
        },

        add: function(){
            this.parent.another_obj = 'Another';
            this.parent.another_type = 'another string';
        }
    };

    var oo_var = new OO({name: 'Apple'}); // This var doesn't refresh the obj & type property values applied in change() function. But has properties added in add() function.
```

I have many levels nested objects with siblings in each level.

Comment: Your `init` method does write to `oo_var.obj` and `.type` after the creation of the child object - and after it `.change()`d them.

Comment: What do you really want? And why would the creation of an object change its parent?

Comment: @Bergi, I'm changing parent properties from child. When I look after changing them ( console.log inside change() ), it looks fine. But when I look from outside (console.log after var oo_var = ...), parent still has initial values. See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7rp1qxta/)

Comment: I want to be able to change parent / grandparent's property values from children and access them through `oo_var`.

Comment: You already *can* access and change the parents from the children. Your problem is that your parent initialisation happens after your child's initialisation, so the "changed" values will get overwritten by the "initial" values. Your `init` method should not call `change` or `add`. Why would it need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor should only do the creation, and not change state of anything. It should not need to call an `init` method, and it should definitely not call (even indirectly) a `change` method.

Make it

```
function OO(o, parent) {
    this.parent = parent || null;
    this.type = typeof o;
    this.obj = this.type === 'object' ? new OO(o.name, this) : o;
}
OO.prototype.change = function() {
    this.parent.obj = 'Orange'; // Holds {} before changing
    this.parent.type = 'string'; // 'object' before changing
};
OO.prototype.add = function(){
    this.parent.another_obj = 'Another';
    this.parent.another_type = 'another string';
};

var oo_var = new OO({name: 'Apple'});
console.dir(oo_var);
oo_var.obj.change();
oo_var.obj.add();
console.dir(oo_var);
```

It's also a bit weird ([if not wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)) to have the child change the parent instead of the parent changing itself.

If you don't want to call the methods yourself, you can use a method for that:

```
OO.prototype.init = function() {
    if (this.type === 'object' ) {
        this.obj.init();
    } else if (this.type === 'string') {
        this.change();
        this.add();
    }
};

var oo_var = new OO({name: 'Apple'});
console.dir(oo_var);
oo_var.init();
console.dir(oo_var);
```